# Is there a way to refresh the list in an object dropdown using new query conditions ?

Tags: rally

Using the object dropdown component I want to change the query and display a new list of items. Is that possible once the component has been created ? 
http://developer.rallydev.com/help/object-dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to destroy the dropdown and recreate it again. Only a few of the AppSDK 1.0 components can reload their own data.

Answer (score 1):

The ComboBoxes in the new App SDK 2.0 can be refreshed by calling load on its underlying store again (passing new filters, context, etc.)